# Validación de campos de un formulario antes de su envío

Tags: php, javascript, html

He hecho un fomulario simple en el que hay que meter un mail que cumpla un patron, una pregunta que su longitud sea mayor de 10 caracteres y la complejidad de la pregunta (un número entre 1 y 5). También hay que poner dos respuestas erroneas a la pregunta y una respuesta correcta.
El problema es que quiero que no se pueda dar a mandar (o que al darle no haga nada) si uno de estos requerimientos no se cumple. Al dar a mandar si está todo bien escrito iría a una página php simple con el código:

```
<?php phpinfo();?>
```

Esta más tarde se sustituirá por un código para subirlo a una base de datos.

El problema es que no sé que hay que poner para que mire primero los patters antes de cambiar a la página del php.

Este sería el código (JS arriba, HTML abajo):

```js
    <meta name="tipo_contenido" content="text/html;" http-equiv="content-type" charset="utf-8">
 <title>Quizzes</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesPWS/style.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' 
     type='text/css' 
     media='only screen and (min-width: 530px) and (min-device-width: 481px)'
     href='stylesPWS/wide.css' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' 
     type='text/css' 
     media='only screen and (max-width: 480px)'
     href='stylesPWS/smartphone.css' />
      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#botoia").click(function(){
   var posta = $("#posta").val();
   var galdera = $("#galdera").val();
   var erantzunZuzena = $("#erantzunZuzena").val();
   var erantzunOkerra1 = $("#erantzunOkerra1").val();
   var erantzunOkerra2 = $("#erantzunOkerra2").val();
   var erantzunOkerra3 = $("#erantzunOkerra2").val();
   var zailtasuna = $("#zailtasuna").val();
   var arloa = $("#arloa").val();
   
   var zuzena = true;
   var postaPatroia = new RegExp("[a-z]{2,}[0-9]{3}@ikasle.ehu.(eus||es)");
   
   if(posta.length == ("0") || galdera.length == ("0") || erantzunZuzena.length == ("0") || erantzunOkerra1.length == ("0") || erantzunOkerra2.length == ("0") || erantzunOkerra3.length == ("0") || zailatasuna.length == ("0") || arloa.length == ("0")){
    alert("Derrigorrezko eremuren bat betetzea falta zaizu");
    zuzena=false;
   } else {
    if(!postaER.test(posta)){
     alert("Ez duzu sartu baliozko posta");
     zuzena=false;
    }
    if((/[1-5]/).test(zailtasuna)){
    }else {
     alert("Zailtasunaren balioa 1 eta 5en artean egon behar da hauek barne");
     zuzena=false;
    }
    if(galdera.length<("10")){
      alert("Galderak 10 karaktere edo gehiago eduki behar ditu");
      zuzena=false;
    }
   }
   
   if(!postaPatroia.test(posta) || (/[1-5]/).test(zailtasuna) || (galdera.length<"10"){
     alert("Daturen bat txarto sartu da");
     return false;
   }
  });
  
  $("#reset").click(function(){
   $("#posta").val(""); $("#galdera").val(""); $("#erantzunZuzena").val(""); $("#erantzunOkerra1").val(""); 
   $("#erantzunOkerra2").val(""); $("#erantzunOkerra3").val(""); $("#zailtasuna").val(""); $("#arloa").val("");
  });
 });
 
  </script>
```

```
<section class="main" id="s1">
<div>
    <form id="formularioa" name="form" action="../lab0.php" method="POST">
        <strong> Posta (*):  <strong> <input type="text" id="posta" required/><br>
        <strong> Galdera (*):  </strong> <input type="text" id="galdera" required/><br>
        </strong>Erantzun zuzena (*): </strong> <input type="text" id="erantzunZuzena" required/><br>
        <strong> Erantzun okerra 1 (*): </strong> <input type="text" id="erantzunOkerra1" required/><br>
        <strong> Erantzun okerra 2 (*): <strong> <input type="text" id="erantzunOkerra2" required/><br>
        <strong>Erantzun okerra 3 (*):</strong> <input type="text" id="erantzunOkerra3" required/><br>
        <strong>Zailtasuna(1 - 5) (*): </strong> <input type="text" id="zailtasuna" required/><br>
        <strong>Arloa: </strong> <input type="text" id="arloa"/></br>

        <input type="submit" id="botoia" value="Bidali"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br>

        <div id="aster" ><strong> * | Nahitaezko hutsuneak </strong></div><br><br>
    </form>
</div>
</section>
<footer class='main' id='f1'>
    <p><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiz" target="_blank">What is a Quiz?</a></p>
    <a href='https://github.com'>Link GITHUB</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: Edito el título y las etiquetas para aclarar el problema de tu caso y conseguir un mejor punto de vista desde donde ayudarte. Hasta que sea visible el cambio intentare yo mismo responderte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La idea es retornar `false` en la validación para impedir que el formulario sea enviado. El problema es que eso debes hacerlo en el evento `onsubmit` del form.

```
<form id="formularioa" name="form" action="../lab0.php"
         method="POST" onsubmit="return validarForm();">
</form>
```

Ahí si, va a bloquear el envío si se retorna false.

```
function validarForm(){
    if(emailEsCorrecto())
      return true;
    else
      return false;
}
```

Otra opción es llamar `e.preventDefault()` pero para eso tienes que declarar el evento.

Además si hay errores al ejecutar la función entonces no llegará a retornar false y puede que envíe el formulario, por lo que te recomiendo que también valides del lado del servidor, así previenes insertar basura en la base de datos si el browser tiene JavaScript desactivado o hay algún ataque malintencionado.

Answer (score 1):

Siempre que hablamos de un formulario web y expresamente de su validación debemos tener en cuenta que existen varios puntos a tener en cuenta para llevarla a cabo.

Por un lado podemos validar un formulario web solo gracias a los atributos html de sus elementos(input, form, textarea ,fieldset y button). Estaríamos hablando de una validación solo en el lado cliente.

Como segunda opción podemos validar el valor de elementos del formulario antes de enviar la solicitud ayudándonos con Javascript. Por ejemplo aplicando un evento que ejecute una función javascript, ya sea por atributo html o directamente con javascript.

Y por ultimo y creo que más importante estaría la validación por parte del código del servidor que evaluaría los datos enviados para prevenir cualquier error de validación en lado cliente o intento de envío de datos fraudulento.

Todos deberían ser necesarios y estar presentes en todos los formularios que hagas.

Para dar respuesta a tu caso en concreto y viendo que el ejemplo que pones tiene un backend bastante simple, me centrare en los dos primeros y sin centrarme en la lógica de la validación si no como llegar a poder ejecutarla.

- Validación con atributos:

Desde hace un tiempo es posible aplicar el atributo pattern junto al required para validar en lado cliente.

```js
function envio() {
  alert("El envio funciono solo validandose los atributos");
}
```

```html
<!-- utilizamos javascript: envio() para simular que 
lo enviamos -->
<form action="javascript: envio()">
<input type="text" placeholder="Debe empezar por 1" pattern="1.*" required />
<button type="submit">Enviar</button>
<form>
```

más información [aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)( en inglés pero con ejemplos ejecutables ;) )

- Validación con javascript:
  Al igual que en el anterior podríamos usar javascript para enviarlo, pero aumentando el nivel de validación ya que en podríamos editar el código HTML con herramientas como el inspeccionador de elementos dejando vía abierta a introducir cualquier valor.

```js
function validar(event) {
  //nuestro boton de tipo submit ejecuta esta funcion
  //tras ejecutarse esta funcion se ejecuta automaticamente 
  //la del action de nuestro form, pero si cancelamos el evento
  //cancelara la ejecucion del action.
  //en el caso de usar el evento onsubmit del propio
  //form solo nos bastaria devolver false para parar el envio

  //cualquier tipo de validacion , expresion regular etc,
  if(miCampo.value.indexOf('1') !== 0){
  //no ejecuta el submit
    event.preventDefault();
    //previene la ejecucion de eventos 
    //adjuntados a elementos padres
    event.stopPropagation();

    //muestro error, alerta ...
    alert("El valor no empieza por 1")
  }

  //llamo otra funcion o dejo que se ejecute el action
  
}

function enviar(){
   alert("todo se envio")
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript: enviar()">
  <input type="text" id="miCampo" name="campo1" placeholder="Empieza por 1" pattern="1.*" />
<button type="submit" onclick="validar(event)"> Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Cabe decir que el action luego debería ser por ejemplo procesar.php

- Como último punto y como dije antes cualquier evento subscrito a un elemento html por medio de atributos es subceptible de ser eliminado modificando el DOM del documento HTML, siendo más aconsejable utilizar un addEventListener por javascript. A su vez cualquier event adjuntado a un elemento sería casi igual de fácil eliminarlo, por lo que la opción de validar en servidor es y será la única imprescindible.

Bueno espero que te sirva y bienvenido al desarrollo web.